# Laravel Mail to Log

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have my Laravel Mail driver setup as to print to my log file:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'log'),
```

When I send mail, however, I am receiving a swiftmail authentication error:

> Expected response code 250 but got code '530' with message '530 5.7.1
>   Authentication required'
>
> ```
> vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\AbstractSmtpTransport.php
> ```
>
> line 383\">AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383
>
> ```
> 530 5.7.1 Authentication required
> ```

Is there another setting I need to set somewhere? Why is it trying to use swiftmailer?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This is in your mail.php config file...

When using

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'log'),
```

This will get the MAIL_DRIVER environment variable set in your .env file. In this case, 'log' is used only as a default if a value is not specified in your .env file... Your .env file probably has this still set in it... set it to log...

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
```

replace with

```
MAIL_DRIVER=log
```

**NOTE:** For laravel >= 7.x `MAIL_DRIVER` replaced with `MAIL_MAILER` variable

Comment: As a comment to this, if you are running the server through `php artisan serve` you might have to restart the server for the .env file to be reloaded.

Comment: My friend @MarkSkayff, you just saved me keep my sanity after hours of debugging and googling...

Comment: If already have currently running workers, don't forget to restart them with `php artisan queue:restart`

Comment: If the `.env` is set correctly try running `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 5):

One more reason why your `MAIL_DRIVER=log` configuration may not be working as expected is that you have your `QUEUE_DRIVER` set to something other than `sync`.

Thanks to the tip by [gibex on Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-email-not-sending-mail-nor-logging-in-the-log-file?page=1#reply=306958).

Answer (score 4):

Laravel use .ENV file!

Maybe your edit config\mail.php, try to make edits in the ENV file

Make dump the variable with your current mail configuration

Put this code in your controller

```
dd(config('mail'));
```

You will see the current settings that the system uses.

Comment: In addition to that, you may need to run `php artisan config:cache` after you change config settings before the new settings take effect.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone encounters this error on L5.8 even after setting your mail driver to 'log' in the env file.

> Swift_TransportException (530) Expected response code 250 but got code
>   "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required "

You need to restart your web server, and restart "php artisan serve" as well.
If it still doesn't work, you need to clear the configuration cache with `php artisan config:clear`