# set laravel mail setting to log file

Tags: laravel

I just start to learning laravel and now I have a problem with mail settings.

I want to send reset password email to the log file of the project and for this I change the **.env** file settings from **MAIL_DRIVER = smtp** to **MAIL_DRIVER = log**

I also change the **mail.php** settings and reset my server because I use (php artisan serve) command.

still i receive following error

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mytodo.password_resets' doesn't exist (SQL: delete from `password_resets` where `email` = Ali@gmail.com

I don't know why it is search for table.

I also see the following question it has same problem but my problem doesn't solve by their instruction.

[Laravel Mail to Log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798745/laravel-mail-to-log?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

please help me is there anything else i should try.

Comment: could you check your database? did you have table named `password_resets`? if not, perhaps `php artisan auth:publish` can help, it should add 2 migration files and you can manifest the table by running `php artisan migrate`..

Comment: Share your code

Comment: are you able to send reset password email through regular smtp driver as it will confirm you dont have any error in database or code. If sending mail gets success on smtp than in log its just matter of changing the driver setting in .env which you have already done.

Comment: i don't have password_resets table and the command you mention (php artisan auth:publish) doesn't work for me. if i create table by my own which columns should it has

Comment: I create the **password_resets** table in database and now it is working, although the settings in **.env** file is set to **log** and the address for resetting password will save in **log** file. I still don't know why laravel needs to use table, even I change the **smtp** to **log** inside the **env** file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table must be created to store the password reset tokens and There is our processes :

1. Get reset request
2. Generate token
3. Store token in DB
4. Send email

In your way, you only change step **4**. You need store tokens and you should have a `password_resets` table in your database.